# avoid image scaling bug with jQuery custom content scroller

Tags: jquery, image-scaling, custom-scrolling

What is the best practices to avoid the image scaling bug on the [**jQuery custom content scroller**](https://github.com/malihu/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin)?

*The problem result's in that the image is set to a `width: 100%`. When the custom scroller is added the `width` change which affects the `height` and reduces the content of an amount where no scroller is needed anymore.*

[image: example gif]

See the example below or as [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wittich/hskajkep/):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#content").mCustomScrollbar({
        axis: 'y',
        theme: 'dark-3'
    });
});
```

```css
html { background-color: #ccc; }
.container { height: 200px; width:180px; overflow:auto; }
.image { width: 100%; }
.test { background-color: #fff; }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin/3.1.1/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin/3.1.1/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min.js"></script>

<div id="content" class="container">
   <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b3/NGC_1232.jpg/300px-NGC_1232.jpg" class="image" />
   <div class="test">Astronomy</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

add this line to you css after you include scrollbar .css:

```
.mCSB_container.mCS_no_scrollbar_y.mCS_y_hidden {
    margin-right: 30px;
}
```

it will add the margin no matter if scroll is present or is not.

The only minus is, even when there is no scroll you will have a margin.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#content").mCustomScrollbar({
        axis: 'y',
        theme: 'dark-3'
    });
});
```

```css
html { background-color: #ccc; }
.container { height: 200px; width:180px; overflow:auto; }
.image { width: 100%; }
.test { background-color: #fff; }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin/3.1.1/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<style> 
.mCSB_container.mCS_no_scrollbar_y.mCS_y_hidden {
    margin-right: 30px;
}
</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin/3.1.1/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min.js"></script>

<div id="content" class="container">
   <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b3/NGC_1232.jpg/300px-NGC_1232.jpg" class="image" />
   <div class="test">Astronomy</div>
</div>
```